# Can I create methods in JSPs?

Tags: java, jsp

Can I write methods in JSPs? (Java Server Pages)

I tried writing a method within the body of the JSP, but my IDE doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 1):

JSP can only show information to user, if you want to do some elaboration you have to re-call a servlet that to that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Analize and try using this:
Everything in your jsp.

But i recommend you that if your a gonna use methods, use classes instead. They are safer and loads quite faster when calling them.

```
<%
   //Your main logic
   out.print(myMethod());
%>
<html>
     your client side content
</html>
<%!
   public String myMethod(){
      return "Method called successfully";
   }
%>
```